# Select and Update form from table using php and mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

After writing a code to echo the result of my mysql to my database table, now am trying to get the selected row to be on my update page as as as show some information from the table and as well as being able to update the table at the same time

Am getting confused with all the online help i have actually read in other to make this work, but i believe i wrote the right code but might just be missing something in which i believe some on can help me with.
**here is index.php** that display the table from my database

```
<?php
//include auth.php file on all secure pages
require("../db.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login");
exit(); }
?>
<?php require_once('header.php')?>  

<div class="container content">


  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
        <thead>  
          <tr>
       <th>ConsignmentNo</th>
        <th>Origin</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>PickupDate</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th >Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM consignment");
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['consignmentno'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentorigin'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentdestination'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentpickupdate'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentstatus'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a name='consignmentno' href='update.php?id=".$row['consignmentno']."'>Edit</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                                                    }
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
            </tbody>
      </table>  
      </div>






</div>

<?php require_once('footer.php')?>
```

And here is the 
**update.php**page that process my request

```
<?php
require("../db.php");
$track = $_GET['consignmentno']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `consignment` WHERE consignmentno='$track'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$consignmentno = $row['consignmentno'];

$shippername = $row['shippername'];

$shipperphone = $row['shipperphone'];

$shipperaddress = $row['shipperaddress'];

$shipperemail = $row['shipperemail'];

$receivername = $row['receivername'];

$receiverphone = $row['receiverphone'];

$receiveraddress = $row['receiveraddress'];

$receiveremail = $row['receiveremail'];

$shipmenttype = $row['shipmenttype'];

$shipmentweight = $row['shipmentweight'];

$shipmentcourier = $row['shipmentcourier'];

$shipmentpackage = $row['shipmentpackage'];

$shipmentmode = $row['shipmentmode'];

$shipmentproduct = $row['shipmentproduct'];

$shipmentquantity = $row['shipmentquantity'];

$shipmentfrieght = $row['shipmentfrieght'];

$shipmentcarrier = $row['shipmentcarrier'];

$departeddate = $row['departeddate'];

$shipmentorigin = $row['shipmentorigin'];

$shipmentdestination = $row['shipmentdestination'];

$shipmentpickupdate = $row['shipmentpickupdate'];

$shipmentstatus = $row['shipmentstatus'];

$shipmentexpected = $row['shipmentexpected'];

$comment = $row['comment'];
     }

} else {
     echo "NO DETAILS FOR USER";
}

$con->close();
?>
<?php require_once('header.php')?>  

<div class="container content">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


txt=$("#UpdateStatus").val();



if(txt=='3')
{

$("#receive").slideDown("slow");

$("#UpdateReceivedBy").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else
{
$("#receive").slideUp("slow");
 $('#UpdateReceivedBy').attr('disabled', 'true');

}


  $("#UpdateStatus").change(function(){

       txt=$("#UpdateStatus").val();



if(txt=='3')
{
$("#receive").slideDown("slow");
$("#UpdateReceivedBy").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else
{
$("#receive").slideUp("slow");
 $('#UpdateReceivedBy').attr('disabled', 'true');

}



  });
});

</script>


<h2 class="col-md-offset-5">Update Shipment</h2>





     <div class="row">
     <div class="table-responsive col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

     <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><h4><?php echo $consignmentno ; ?></h4> 

            </th>

            <th>

<h2>On Hold</h2>     
      </th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
```

but it is not echoing the `$consignmentno` cause if it can do that then every other things becomes easier

and here is an image [image]that shows that my index page is working fine

So please help me check were i got it all wrong. Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: $track=$_GET['id'], that's your mistake

Comment: Btw, your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must replace `update.php?id=` with `update.php?consignmentno=` on `line 35` it will resolve your issue

Or use this code in **index.php**

```
<?php
//include auth.php file on all secure pages
require("../db.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login");
exit(); }
?>
<?php require_once('header.php')?>  

<div class="container content">


  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
        <thead>  
          <tr>
       <th>ConsignmentNo</th>
        <th>Origin</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>PickupDate</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th >Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM consignment");
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['consignmentno'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentorigin'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentdestination'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentpickupdate'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['shipmentstatus'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a name='consignmentno' href='update.php?consignmentno=".$row['consignmentno']."'>Edit</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                                                    }
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
            </tbody>
      </table>  
      </div>
</div>

<?php require_once('footer.php')?>
```

Comment: thanks @Rtra i never noticed that line as the problem initially.